# Evenly spaced <li> inline with fixed image

Tags: html, css

I have the following elements.  The image is fixed at 325X70px and is placed at the top left corner. I want the list items, evenly spaced, to fill the remainder of the width and be responsive to browser resize.  I'm sure this is easy, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="image">Image Here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>X</li>
            <li>Y</li>
            <li>Z</li>
            <li>A</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>`
```

CSS

```css
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
        
}
.left {
    float: left;
   
  
}
.image {
    min-width: 325px;
    max-width: 325px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: red;

}
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: black;
   
    
}
.menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    display: table;
  
    
}
.menu li {
    color: #FFF;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    list-style-type: none;
  
}
```

Comment: Where's your CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not need the `.left` class, you might be able to just do that styling on the image itself, but regardless, what needs to happen here is that `.left` and `.menu` need to be side by side. To do that...

```
.left,
.menu {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;}
```

We know the image is always 325px wide, so let's set the parent container to match...

```
.left {
    width:325px;}
```

And then we want `.menu` to be the entire width of the screen, minus that image/container, so can we do this...

```
.menu {
    width: calc(100% - 325px);}
```

You'll still have to turn your `li` horizontal...

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;}
```

Comment: thanks.  I changed the .menu class to have a width of (100% - 325px) and it worked like a charm.  Much appreciated.